# M1 Mac mini - Your computer was restarted because of a problem

Tags: big-sur, bug, restart

I've used my M1 Mac mini for about a month and already got about five crashes/reboots. Whenever this happened, I hadn't been doing anything special, nothing that was related to any installed software.

This time, I simply watched a YouTube video and wanted to pause it. My mouse froze for 5 seconds, a pink screen appeared and then the Mac rebooted.

I got the "Your computer was restarted because of a problem." message and this report. I have no idea how to read this. Is there anybody who can see what's wrong with my mac?

```
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xfffffe00245944c4): "dart-disp0 (0xfffffe2336968000): SMMU(SMMU) error: SID 0 PTE invalid exception on read with DVA 0x1288000 (TTBR 0 SEG 0 PTE 0x4a2) ERROR_STATUS 0x80000004 TIME 0x66f193c5c01 TTE 0 AXI_ID 0)"
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 20D64
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:06:51 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101
Fileset Kernelcache UUID: F08F12DFF70C39DBC0CC09CC01116325
Kernel UUID: 9FE8C0DA-8ED0-381C-9CEC-2A779F3E1503
iBoot version: iBoot-6723.81.1
secure boot?: YES
Paniclog version: 13
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001b3ec000
KernelCache base:  0xfffffe00223f0000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001bf20000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffe0022f24000
Kernel text exec base:  0xfffffe0022fec000
mach_absolute_time: 0x2787c9ed9b
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x6024f8cd 0x0006edfc
  Sleep   : 0x60250cf5 0x00054758
  Wake    : 0x60250e3a 0x00045092
  Calendar: 0x602515ad 0x000978ac

CORE 0 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c0c
CORE 1 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c0c
CORE 2 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c0c
CORE 3 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023155748
CORE 4 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c10
CORE 5 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c10
CORE 6 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c10
CORE 7 recently retired instr at 0xfffffe0023156c10
Panicked task 0xfffffe166d4c98e0: 164836 pages, 482 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xfffffe166d6ba610, backtrace: 0xfffffe304b2b74e0, tid: 449
          lr: 0xfffffe0023039fd0  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7550
          lr: 0xfffffe0023039d9c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b75c0
          lr: 0xfffffe002315bf0c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b75e0
          lr: 0xfffffe002314d8b8  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7690
          lr: 0xfffffe0022ff37e8  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b76a0
          lr: 0xfffffe0023039a2c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7a30
          lr: 0xfffffe0023039a2c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7aa0
          lr: 0xfffffe00237d465c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7ac0
          lr: 0xfffffe00245944c4  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7ae0
          lr: 0xfffffe00245910e0  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7d40
          lr: 0xfffffe0024590c1c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7dd0
          lr: 0xfffffe0024590470  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7e80
          lr: 0xfffffe002370b284  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7ec0
          lr: 0xfffffe002373f778  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7f20
          lr: 0xfffffe0024146808  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7fb0
          lr: 0xfffffe0023731694  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7fc0
          lr: 0xfffffe00231501bc  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7fe0
          lr: 0xfffffe0022ff385c  fp: 0xfffffe304b2b7ff0
          lr: 0xfffffe0023061dac  fp: 0xfffffe3f40d3bee0
          lr: 0xfffffe0023061fb8  fp: 0xfffffe3f40d3bf00
          lr: 0xfffffe0022ffcc14  fp: 0x0000000000000000
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART(1.0)[8CE20231-0416-310B-BFA4-3861C14A7C0F]@0xfffffe002458c000->0xfffffe0024597fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[53D29C42-BCB1-384D-BE79-DAB9ED503C6C]@0xfffffe002392c000->0xfffffe0023977fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily(1)[AC191CE6-9C7A-3BDC-B2C9-E077ADE86866]@0xfffffe0025068000->0xfffffe002507bfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController(1.0d1)[B5629E50-71D8-3336-9FEB-315F74FD0954]@0xfffffe0024144000->0xfffffe0024147fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform(1.0.2)[53D29C42-BCB1-384D-BE79-DAB9ED503C6C]@0xfffffe002392c000->0xfffffe0023977fff

last started kext at 505535571: com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1 (addr 0xfffffe002241c000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AppleALSColorSensor    1.0.0d1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.fileutil  20.036.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    8.0.3d9
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  436.40.6
com.apple.driver.BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPVoiceTrigger   11.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 4.0.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    11.0.0
com.apple.driver.CoreKDL    1
com.apple.driver.SEPHibernation 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBDeviceNCM  5.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.ReadWriteDiskImage  493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.UDIFDiskImage   493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.RAMBackingStore 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.FileBackingStore    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  1677.81.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.filesystems.tmpfs 1
com.apple.IOTextEncryptionFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  556.60.1
com.apple.security.BootPolicy   1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartIO2  1
com.apple.driver.ApplePMPFirmware   1
com.apple.AppleEmbeddedSimpleSPINORFlasher  1
com.apple.driver.AppleCS42L83Audio  437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleTAS5770LAmp   437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMIPMU   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAVD   376
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileDispH13G-DCP    140.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAVE2  401.63.3
com.apple.driver.AppleJPEGDriver    4.6.0
com.apple.AGXG13G   172.26.2
com.apple.driver.AudioDMAController-T8103   1.59
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103CLPCv3   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPIMC 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020SOCTuner 1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostT8103  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XNCO   1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PMGR 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000AES  1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8920XPWM   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS8000DWI  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8960XWatchDogTimer 1
com.apple.driver.AppleInterruptController   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothModule   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSamsungSerial 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCDP29XXUpdateSupport 1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8020DART 1
com.apple.driver.AppleS5L8940XI2C   1.0.0d2
com.apple.driver.AppleM68Buttons    1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8101 1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOKitRegistryCompatibility  1
com.apple.iokit.EndpointSecurity    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDiskImages2   1
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 2.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   310
com.apple.kec.InvalidateHmac    1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 930.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   900.11
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  401.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   300.6.1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAOPAudio  14.32
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHostControllerPCIeTransport 8.0.3d9
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  8.0.3d9
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedIPCOLYBTControl  1
com.apple.driver.AppleConvergedPCI  1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebug    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleEmbeddedUSBXHCIPCI    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSB   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPHDCPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleSEPGenericTransfer 1
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages.KernelBacked    493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    8.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltUSBDownAdapter 1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBTM   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBSDKextStarter    3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleDCPDPTXProxy  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPDPFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextG13GRTBuddy    172.26.2
com.apple.AGXFirmwareKextRTBuddy64  172.26.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSPU   1
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDiagnosticDataAccessReadOnly  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleNANDConfigAccess  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCSEmbeddedAudio   437.96
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudio 437.96
com.apple.iokit.AppleARMIISAudio    80.34
com.apple.driver.AppleDialogPMU 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleStockholmControl  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.DCPAVFamilyProxy   1
com.apple.driver.AppleSPMI  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily-DCP  343.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOMobileGraphicsFamily  343.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDCP   1
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareKit   1
com.apple.driver.AppleH11ANEInterface   4.52.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGPUFamily 20.23
com.apple.driver.AppleSART  1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCA2-T8103    510.72
com.apple.driver.ApplePassthroughPPM    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103TypeCPhy 1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCIARM    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXDCI   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBDeviceFamily   2.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIARM    1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedUSBHost   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePMGR  1
com.apple.driver.watchdog   1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleDisplayCrossbar   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTypeCPhy  1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    7.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIeC    1
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 9.3.2
com.apple.driver.ApplePIODMA    1
com.apple.driver.AppleT8103PCIe 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothDebugService 1
com.apple.driver.AppleBCMWLANCore   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211FamilyV2 1200.12.2b1
com.apple.driver.IOImageLoader  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IODisplayPortFamily 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGPIOICController  1.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileApNonce 1
com.apple.driver.AppleFireStormErrorHandler 1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultiFunctionManager  1
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedPCIE  1
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    900.11
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    585
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   8.0.3d9
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothPacketLogger 8.0.3d9
com.apple.driver.FairPlayIOKit  68.6.0
com.apple.iokit.CoreAnalyticsFamily 1
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPKeyStore   2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    511.60.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  184.40.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   436.40.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   436.40.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIPAppender    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.RTBuddy    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedTempSensor    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPMU    1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAccessoryManager  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleA7IOP 1.0.2
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.driver.AppleBiometricSensor   2
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.AUC   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAVFamily  1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHDCPFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCECFamily 1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudio2Family  1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedAudioLibs 1.17
com.apple.driver.AppleFirmwareUpdateKext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleM2ScalerCSCDriver 265.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   289.3
com.apple.driver.IODARTFamily   1
com.apple.security.quarantine   4
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.security.AppleImage4  3.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOCryptoAcceleratorFamily   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform   1.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    11.1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1



** Stackshot Succeeded ** Bytes Traced 409048 (Uncompressed 1076576) **
```

Comment: Does the issue occur when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: I never tested this because it happens maybe only once a week. So I think I need to be in safe mode for a whole week or so?

Comment: Can you try using a new user?

Comment: So would this mean there is a problem with the os?

Comment: Usually a kernel panic is a bug in the OS

Answer (score 1):

Examining the panic signature, I can see that this is the result of a bug in the OS. There’s nothing wrong on your end. The most helpful thing you can do is to make sure you’ve [opted in to share analytics](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-analytics-information-mac-apple-mh27990/mac) which will allow your panic reports to anonymously get sent to Apple so that their engineers can work on fixing the bug.

That being said, one experiment you can try, if you have the hardware, is to use a different display hardware configuration. That is, either:

1. Connect a different display to your Mac,
2. Connect the same display over a different link (i.e., Thunderbolt instead of HDMI or vice versa), or
3. Run without a display using Screen Sharing to another Mac.

If you can try one of these (or, better yet, all three of these!) for a week or more, it would be good data to know if the panics continue or stop.

Comment: I already shared the analytics.

I am still not quite sure where the issue could be or what type of error this is. Is it hardware related or related with the hardware that is connected to my mac? Because you suggested to test another monitor.

Is it even possible to read the type of error from the log above?

Unfortunately, I do not have another monitor to test. I want to order a new one but due to unavailability I still have to wait some weeks till my new monitor arrives.

Comment: @Micha125 Did you receive a new monitor for testing?